# Delete watch-only imported address bitcoin-core

Tags: bitcoin-core, watch-only

Is it possible to delete imported watch-only address? I know it's not possible using RPC commands. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are feeling brave, you can edit the wallet.dat file itself to remove those. You can use the db4.8_dump and db4.8_load utilities to modify it. Note that doing so may result in database corruption and I would not recommend it. That is really the only way to delete anything from Bitcoin Core's wallet.